# response.flushBuffer() is not working

Tags: java, servlets, streaming, oracle11g, blob

I am trying to implement a servlet for streaming large objects:

```
    oracle.sql.BLOB blob = rs.getBLOB('obj');
    InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream();

    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

    int counter=0
    while((length=in.read(buffer)) != -1){
        out.write(buffer,0,length);
        counter++;
        if(counter % 10 == 0){
        counter=0;
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
```

This code suppose to send data to client chunk by chunck. Now what's happening is that when I stream large object (100 MB), memory goes up, and server dies sometimes if there are more than one parallel downloads/stream.

Why this `flushBuffer()` is not sending data to client? The client get popup for open/save file only after response closes.

Comment: In addition i use JOBSS 4.3 sever for testing this code

Comment: do you somewhere `out.close()`?

Comment: yes i do out.close() but not pasted here

Comment: Is it working with smaller streams? If yes there must be somewhere settings to tune this up, I believe setting log level to finest might be helpful here.

Comment: I believe it's a app-server configuration. Please, see [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453508/end-to-end-reactive-streaming-restful-service).

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the `Content-Length` header before writing the data, or the server is forced to buffer all the data until the stream is closed, at which point it can calculate the value itself, write the header, and send all the data. As soon as you get the output stream, before you write any data at all, set the content length:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(blob.length()));
```

Most servers are smart enough to flush the buffer themselves at this point, so you probably don't even need to call `flushBuffer()` -- although it doesn't hurt.

Comment: I tired this. Its not happeing :-)

Comment: Depending on your preference, you could also do `response.setContentLength(blob.length());`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need a response header for the `servlet` response so that the container can know after how many bytes can the information end:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(blob.length()));
```